# Loading Webview is not filled with device screen?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a problem with webview. It is not loaded with full screen. I have tried all post answer from stackoverflow but couldn't solve my problem (webview width  and height are match-parent/fill-parent i tried for both)

I am using this in html

```
<meta content="height = device-height,width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, minimum-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 2.0, target-densitydpi = dpi_value"/>
```

And in code am setting the map settings as well

```
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

I have tried with support for all screens in manifest like

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true" />
```

I am loading the add image from server (image size is 800x720). and only image i am loading not any other data.

Answer (score 1):

Add this command in your webview settings

```
webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you support all screen sizes?

Add following to the manifest:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your layout look like? Make sure your `layout_width` and `layout_height` are set to `"fill_parent"`. I think it's set to `wrap_content` by default.

```
    <WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: Hi i tried with all combinations but couldn't get solution. Because i am loading the image with 800x720