# WebView height doesn't fill the screen, even though it is defined as fill_parent

Tags: android, webview

The WebView is giving me a headache.

As you can see in the layout, i am defining the WebView with fill_parents. Which seems to be displaying perfectly in ADT.

The problems start when the initial web page that I load is smaller height wise than the webview, then somehow the webview gets resized and displays the smaller web page with a black screen under the webview. It seems as the webview reverts to wrap_content.

If the initial webpage that I load is bigger than the webview, then I can still load a smaller website and the webview stays with fill_parent.

I tried with all sorts of webview settings, but they doesnt seem to make a difference. Again, if the initial website is big height wise, the problem doesnt show, only if the initial website is small. I hope I am making sense.

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

      <WebView
          android:id="@+id/view2_web"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           />           

    </LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
final WebView view2web   = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.view2_web);
view2web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
view2web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
view2web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
view2web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view2web.loadUrl(url);
```

Edit:
I added the entire layout xml of the activity, I don think that using fill_parent instead of match_parent would leade to a problem there, even though it is deprecated. I will replace it.

Comment: Is that the entire layout file?

Comment: Just a hint: `fill_parent` has been **deprecated** with Froyo (API Level 8)

Comment: Try using `layout_weight=1`

Comment: @CurlyCorvus added the entire layout

Comment: Please include the url you are trying to load also.

Comment: please try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715074/loading-webview-is-not-filled-with-device-screen

Comment: @PetrosMastrantonas is this working ?, please do let me know

Comment: Try this: In your device, go to `Settings > Developer Options ` and turn on `Show layout bounds`. Now go to your screen and take a screenshot and attach that here. I need to make sure if the size of `WebView` is a problem or the size of the webpage loaded is the problem.

Comment: @Awadesh I will try in a few hours when I am home. But I dont see a lot of new things there, maybe the "webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);"

Comment: @Henry I would rather not reveal the app ;-) but I will let you know if Awadeshes answer doesnt work

Comment: Oki. In that case, you could check the results yourself. See if the `WebView` is filled or not.